# R programming - Split a column based on the column values

Tags: r, data-science, data-processing

I have a dataset whose format is shown below:

```
a1    a2    a3 |   class
0     0     0  |   c1
0     0     1  |   c2
0     1     1  |   c3
```

I want to split the column 'class' based on the values of the column. I want the output to look like this:

```
a1    a2    a3 |   c1    c2    c3
0     0     0  |   1     0     0
0     0     1  |   0     1     0
0     1     1  |   0     0     1
```

Here since 'class' contains 3 values, I want to remove the column class and add 3 columns, one for each value. Since the first row had class = c1, in the output dataframe, for the first row, I want c1 =1 and c2, c3 = 0.

What is the best way to do this?

My current code is shown below:

```
#read data
df = df = read.table('source')
names(df) = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "class")

#get new columns to be added
c_data = df['class']
c_types = unique(c_data)
```

I am not too sure how to proceed from here.

One solution that I have thought of is I could create 3 arrays (since I know number of unique elements = 3) for each c_type value and assign values by checking if c_data == c_type and add the arrays as columns to the dataframe but there has to be a better way to do this since this would be very difficult to do if 'class' has a large number of values.

Comment: `cbind(df[-4], as.data.frame.matrix(table(rownames(df), df$class)))` or `library(tidyverse) ; df %>% mutate(i = 1) %>% spread(class, i, fill = 0)`